# What is an alternative word for 'over-lit area'?

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english, british-english

What is an alternative word to tell about 'over lit area'?

I am using it in this example:

> The light from my lamp has over-lit my table.

Comment: "over lit" is not an idiom in English. What do you wish it to mean? What is the function of the word "over"? Do you simply mean "has illuminated"?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I mean to say the areas are over illuminated rather than the required illumination.

Comment: Maybe "too bright"?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK, deadrat What about 'bloom'?

Comment: 'Glare' describes light reflected too brightly from the page. 'Harsh lighting' means it strains the eyes.

Comment: Suggestion: The light from my lamp is too bright for my table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb *[overlight](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/overlight)* (one word) means

> to illuminate too brightly

*Collins*

You are already there

> The light from my lamp has overlit my table.

Comment: There is a danger that "overlit" will be interpreted as meaning "lit from above".

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest

**[to beam](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/beam):**

> 2 [no object, with adverbial of direction]
>
> (Of a light or light source) shine brightly
>
> *The bright lights were still beaming down as bright as ever.* (ODO)

Here's a [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=light+beamed+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Clight%20beamed%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Blight%20beamed%20upon%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Blight%20beamed%20from%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Blight%20beamed%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Blight%20beamed%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Blight%20beamed%20forth%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Blight%20beamed%20through%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Blight%20beamed%20into%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Blight%20beamed%20out%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Blight%20beamed%20over%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Blight%20beamed%20all%3B%2Cc0) showing the 10 most frequently used prepositions with "light beamed..."
some of them are: from, on, upon, over...

So your sentence might read:

> The light from my lamp beamed over my table.*
>
> The light from my lamp beamed on my table.
>
> The light beamed from the lamp above/beside my table.

*Note that this is another meaning of 'over' - here it means to extend over an area (i.e. your table) it is not a prefix over- (used to denote something is excessive) like in your word overlit.

Answer (score 0):

You might try something that would convey the same meaning contextually such as engulfed.

> The light from my lamp engulfed my table

Answer (score 0):

**Furniture Store Lighting**--A phrase used to desrcibe a room or interior of a building with garish overhead fluorescent lighting that permits no shadows. It refers, naturally to the type of lighting used in furniture stores--a harsh glaring light so the customer can't ignore the goods on display.